# Unexpected URI segment in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I am accessing user profile page with this type of url

```
foo.com/index.php/controller/view_profile/user_id
```

its working fine. In the profile page I have different segement of the profile and using buttons for them.

if I click on a button which should take me to user financial data, its redirects to

```
foo.com/index.php/controller/view_profile/user_finance/user_id
```

instead of

```
foo.com/index.php/controller/user_finance/user_id
```

in the button link i just used following code

```
echo '<a href="user_finance/'.$user_id.'"><button class="btn btn-info btn-large">Financial Information</button></a>';
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following to generate the code for the link.

```
$array  =   array(
    'class' =>  '<button class="btn btn-info btn-large">'
);
echo anchor('controller/user_finance/' . $user_id,"Financial Information",$array);
```

EDIT:

The above link you are using wont work as it needs full url which `anchor` helper will generate.